# Determining existence of folder on client's machine in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is there any way I can check the existence of a folder on the client's root on the C drive (assuming the client is using Windows XP) in GWT?  In a way that works both in Firefox and IE at least?

I know that there is a JavaScript way to do it, but as far as I know it only works in IE6.  If this is my only real option, I'll use JSNI to access the following JavaScript:

```
try {
    var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    try {
        fso.GetFolder("C:\\Folder");
        return true;
    } catch (f) {
        return false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, GWT does not have that.

Since GWT is built on 'plain' JavaScript, it can't offer you more. You're stuck to using ActiveX/Flash/Java applets for this.